# How to formulate a computational problem rigorously?

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, books

I often interact with people who want to ask for an algorithm for a computational problem (or its complexity), but they don't express it in a rigorous way for us (computer scientists) to understand.

Referring them to books like CLRS is not helpful because the examples there usually have a quite straightforward way of stating rigorously, e.g. given the adjacency list of a graph and two vertices in it compute the shortest path between those vertices.

> Is there any good book (or some other resource) where a person with minimal knowledge of CS can learn how one should formulate and state computational problems in a rigorous way that is understandable to computer scientists?

Preferably the book should have many examples of how to formulate computational problems rigorously from various domain and real world examples.

---

#### Clarification

To make the question more specific, let's assume that they know basic math/CS terminology like sets, functions, graphs, lists, etc. at the level of 1st/2nd year undergraduate CS student (which is the case with people who I have in mind). For example, they have read some introductory textbook like Aho and Ullman (although they might not have understood it completely).

- Al Aho and Jeff Ullman, [Foundations of Computer Science](http://infolab.stanford.edu/%7Eullman/focs.html), 1992.

Comment: I think this is a good question, but I don't know if there's a good answer. I feel like it's kind of asking for "Is there a way we can teach someone who's not a computer scientist to think like a computer scientist?" And the answer to that is "yes, make them a computer scientist." That said, some software engineering researchers may have done studies on stuff like this.

Comment: Also, I think this is what use cases are for, to a degree. If someone doesn't understand how to properly formulate their problem, the list a number of scenarios of what they'd like a given program to do, and the expected behavior in each case. The programmer then develops a specification from that. That said, I'm a theory person, not an engineer, so if I'm wrong, feel free to correct me.

Comment: @jmite, thank you for the comments. You are right that part of Software Engineering is to try to understand what a client wants (I think they call it [requirement analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_analysis)). But that is usually for large projects. I am not talking about such projects, but simple questions like those we get on this site which are not rigorously stated. I have seen books teaching people how to state a statement in logic with many examples. I am hoping that there is something similar for algorithms and computational problems.

Comment: @jmite, surely a computer scientists can formulate a computational question rigorously, however I don't think the other direction is necessarily true, i.e. asking a computational question rigorously doesn't requires being a computer scientist.

Comment: I think your first problem is that they might not be familiar with CS terminology and the concepts behind it. They would simply need to study computer science to be able to use it properly. But being rigorous with terminology is not actually necessary - look at some problems from programming competitions, they are usually stated in terms a small child could understand (apples, mazes, cities, roads, playing cards...), yet they are still well defined.

Comment: That said, I am of the opinion it requires a certain way of thinking that is not easily acquired, especially by adults. I have tried to get people to drop the technical stuff and explain the problem as simply as possible in terms of everyday objects. The problem is, they will usually forget some constraint, or they will make it sound like an operation that is O(N) in their actual system is O(1), and so on. So I will end up with something very close to a rigorous definition of the wrong problem.

Comment: this is somewhat similar to [using mathematical concepts/writing/notation](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/7367/looking-for-a-dictionary-of-math-cs-notation) correctly.

Comment: in a way, what is asked for is contradictory, because formulating problems rigorously is exactly one of the key learned skills that separates laymen from specialists/professionals...

Comment: @vzn, that is a nice question. However, I don't think the main issue with these people is not knowing enough terminology. And often one can explain a question rigorously without using advanced terminology. In any case, I added a clarification to make the question more specific and closer to what I am looking for.

Comment: @Juho, If you are saying that there are cases which it won't help, that is fine, I am not looking for a perfect solution. But I personally think a book with many examples can be very useful in many cases and would help them at least understand how they should formulate their problems.

Comment: From experience, I would say the only way to figure out what they want is to ***sit down with them and talk.*** If you can't do this, you're not going to get anywhere. Of course, that means that question-and-answer sites like this one aren't very useful in this situation.

Comment: I think jmite got it right in the above comments. Knowing enough about computer science is a prerequisite to being able to rigorously formulate a question; and the amount of knowledge required is great enough to consider those who possess it particularly knowledgeable, significantly more so than most. Learning isn't as much about knowing the right answers as it is about knowing how to ask the right questions; that's your answer right there.

Answer (score 3):

a good resource on/for this, fairly well known by academics but not so widely known outside of specialists, is *Mathematical Writing* by  Donald E. Knuth, Tracy L. Larrabee, and Paul M. Roberts. there is a published book, lecture videos, and a set of notes. it is more written from the perspective of people attempting to master mathematical writing eg for creating papers, but all the advice is highly applicable to the case of laymen attempting to formulate problems precisely. mathematical writing while formidable to learn is the scientific approach to rigorously define/formulate—and as the book details, *solve*, eg via algorithms or proofs—computational/algorithmic problems.

- [Mathematical Writing](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/klr.html) book info
- [Mathematical writing lecture videos index](http://scpd.stanford.edu/knuth/index.jsp)
- [Mathematical writing CS1193 class notes](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/papers/cs1193.pdf)

also, the classic [Garey & Johnson text, Computers & Intractability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Intractability%3a_A_Guide_to_the_Theory_of_NP-Completeness) does not exactly describe how to formulate problems precisely, but it does give many examples, and diverse theoretical/conceptual/technical "patterns", organized into sections of similar problems, which can be used as "building blocks" to describe computational/algorithmic problems.

Comment: Thanks vzn, these are nice resources about writing mathematics but I am not looking for something different. The issue is not writing well in mathematics but resources for people to learn how to formulate computational problems clearly enough so an expert can understand what the person asking the question is looking for and help them.

Comment: yw; you say those are two different things, and in words/phrases they are, but & I say they are [to borrow a software engineering phrase] "tightly coupled"

Answer (score 3):

just ran across this nice/neat, unusual, relatively new/unknown ref on his home page by [Emmanuele Viola](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/viola/), prof (T)CS at Northeastern University)  apparently unpublished elsewhere. 41pp. it starts out with very basic mathematical concepts eg implication and then ranges all the way into advanced topics like the [Erdős–Szekeres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Szekeres_theorem) theorem and [Ramsey theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_theory).

- ["How to think like the pros"](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/viola/papers/pros.pdf) by Emmanuele Viola

Answer (score 0):

Buy the book Algorithms and Data Structures from Robert Lafore.

On this book, every algorithm is explained as a story, very much like a poetry. Then, give the person the Lafore version of an algorithm, and later the CLRS version.

Maybe like this, the person will get a feeling on how to translate from intuitive description to rigorous ones.